# How to insert academic year based on registration date in SQL relational database?

Tags: java, sql, backend

I'm working on a system where I need to insert users into a relational database. Each user has an `academic_year` field that needs to be inserted based on the academic year corresponding to their registration date.

Here's my Java user creation method, where I'm attempting to implement this functionality:

```java
@Override
  public UserDTO createOneUser(String nom, String prenom, String tel, String email, String mdp, Date date_inscription, int annee_academique_par, String role) {
    UserDTO userDTO = myUserFactory.getUserDTO();

    // Extraire l'année de la date d'inscription
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date_inscription);
    int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    String annee_academique = year + "-" + (year + 1);

    PreparedStatement request = dalBackendServices.getPrepareStatement(
            """
            INSERT INTO projetAE.utilisateurs (nom, prenom, tel, email, mdp, date_inscription, annee_academique, role)
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, (SELECT id_annee_academique FROM projetAE.annees_academiques WHERE annee_academique = ?), ?)
            RETURNING id_utilisateur;
            """);

    try {
      request.setString(1, nom);
      request.setString(2, prenom);
      request.setString(3, tel);
      request.setString(4, email);
      request.setString(5, mdp);
      request.setDate(6, date_inscription);
      request.setInt(7, annee_academique_par);
      request.setString(8, role);

      ResultSet result = request.executeQuery();

      if (result.next()) {
        int userId = result.getInt("id_utilisateur");
        return getOneById(userId);
      } else {
        return null; // Échec de l'insertion
      }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      return null;
    }
  }
```

So I tried to extract the academic year with the `String annee_academique = year + "-" + (year + 1)`, but I don't know how to use it in my SQL request.

Comment: `String annee_academique` clearly that variable is a `String`. Why do you expect to be able to assign it to an Integer field in the database? `year + "-" + (year + 1)"` are you trying to perform arithmetic operations on Strings?

Comment: How is `annee_academique_par` *actually* defined? You simply increment the current year by one, irrespective of what date it is? You should, btw, be using `java.time.*`, not outmoded and buggy `java.util.Date` And it would help to show the table definition

Comment: @aled it looks like `annee_academique` is being set to the displayed version of the academic year, where a registration year of 2018 would be stored as `"2018-2019"`

Comment: What is the `annee_academique` column in `projetAE.annees_academiques` representing, and how does `annee_academique_par` relate to it? I concur with @g00se, knowing if that column is an int for the year (ex: 2022) or for years in the school (ex: 3) would help with the math